# Passing an object through WCF service to silverlight

Tags: c#, wcf, entity-framework, silverlight

I have a WCF project within my Silverlight application. The WCF project uses Entity Framework to read from a database, i want to pass a list of objects that reflect rows to the Silverlight application this is the service contract;

```
[ServiceContract]
    public interface IGetToolboxItemsService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        List<Control> GetToolboxItems();

        [OperationContract]
        string ReturnWord(string word);
    }
```

and here is the class that does the work

```
public class GetToolboxItemsService : IGetToolboxItemsService
    {
        public List<Control> GetToolboxItems()
        {
            SilverlightScreenDesignerEntities ent = new SilverlightScreenDesignerEntities();
            List<Control> controls = new List<Control>();
            controls = ent.Controls.ToList();
            return controls;
        }

        public string ReturnWord(string word)
        {
            return word;
        }
    }
```

This is how i call the service in the client;

```
ToolboxServiceReference.GetToolboxItemsServiceClient proxy = new ToolboxServiceReference.GetToolboxItemsServiceClient();
            proxy.GetToolboxItemsCompleted += proxy_GetToolboxItemsCompleted;
            proxy.GetToolboxItemsAsync();
```

and then the completed event is here;

```
void proxy_GetToolboxItemsCompleted(object sender, ToolboxServiceReference.GetToolboxItemsCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            var data = e.Result;
        }
```

when i debug the service it runs off to the database and brings back a list of `Controls` which is whats expected however i get the error message when trying to get the list of controls through the client.

```
The remote server returned an error: NotFound
```

yet when i try the simple return word, the service works fine and nothing breaks, is there an extra step thats needed because im passing through an object?

Here is the web.config;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=4.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
  <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="">
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    </system.serviceModel>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="v11.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
  </entityFramework>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ModelContainer" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model.csdl|res://*/Model.ssdl|res://*/Model.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=MOBINOTE135;initial catalog=BankManager;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
    <add name="SilverlightScreenDesignerEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model.csdl|res://*/Model.ssdl|res://*/Model.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=MOBINOTE135;initial catalog=SilverlightScreenDesigner;integrated security=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True;application name=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Post your web config. Is the service working in WCFClient?

Comment: Do both client and debugger use the same URL? It seems that client cannot find an endpoint.

Comment: Web config added. No the service doesnt work in the WCFClient either, that error says 'An error occurred while receiving the HTTP response to http://localhost:8733/Design_Time_Addresses/WcfServiceLibrary/GetToolboxItemsService/. This could be due to the service endpoint binding not using the HTTP protocol. This could also be due to an HTTP request context being aborted by the server (possibly due to the service shutting down). See server logs for more details.'

Comment: no they dont @VladimirGondarev is there a way to rectify this?

Comment: I find that it's better to use local IIS instead of IIS Express or Cassini when working with Silverlight and WCF. It seems that your ServiceReferences.ClientConfig has a different port for the endpoint configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Is Control your user defined class? If yes, you will have to mark it such that the wcf service can serialize it:

```
[DataContract]
[Serializable]
public class Cat
{
[DataMember]
public int Age {get;set;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that your service reference is going out of scope. I don't have access to visual studio but you want to do something like this.

```
//declare the service outside of the calling routine
ToolboxServiceReference.GetToolboxItemsServiceClient proxy;

private void GetToolboxItems
{
ToolboxServiceReference.GetToolboxItemsServiceClient proxy = new ToolboxServiceReference.GetToolboxItemsServiceClient();
            proxy.GetToolboxItemsCompleted += proxy_GetToolboxItemsCompleted;
            proxy.GetToolboxItemsAsync();
)

void proxy_GetToolboxItemsCompleted(object sender, ToolboxServiceReference.GetToolboxItemsCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            var data = e.Result;
            proxy.close //now close the service
        }
```